# Install fabric sdk python package

Tags: python, sdk, fabric

I am getting this error when I try to install the main package (fabric sdk python):

```
 × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      copying sha3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      running build_ext
      building '_pysha3' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Modules
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Modules\_sha3
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPY_WITH_KECCAK=1 -IC:\Users\SS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\SS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /TcModules/_sha3/sha3module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Modules/_sha3/sha3module.obj
      sha3module.c
      C:\Users\SS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d_hyyrkq\pysha3_1ba60ba8a6364ea5968636e4efdd3db4\Modules\_sha3\backport.inc(78): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pystrhex.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysha3
  Running setup.py clean for pysha3
Failed to build pysha3
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pysha3, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I still get this error while trying to install pysha3 package separately.

I tried to install separately but still got this error.